# Error 91 "Object Variable or With block variable not set" in UserForm01.Show code

Tags: excel, vba, object, range, userform

I have a simple VBA project where I use a UserForm to record data into the workbook pages and have some of the results of the excel calculations displaced on the UserForm. The name of the userForm is UserForm01. I inserted a commandButton/ActiveX control button (I tried both) on the welcome page which I want to open/call my userform and hide workbook. I have been using this simple code to do this action for a long time. But recently I made some changes in Sub UserForm_Initialize module and after that I keep getting

> Error 91; Range Object is not set

or other error signs all related around object not being set.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm01.Show
End Sub
```

where commandbutton is inserted/located on the excel "welcome page" of the vba file. I assigned UserForm01 as Object and set UserForm01= UserForm etc...Alternatively, I Dimensioned UserForm01 as either UserForm or Variant without any positive result...Once in a while code seems to work but than goes to sub UserForm_Initialize where it is stucks again and I get one of the error messages regarding range object not being set etc..???? I will appreciate any help on this matter...which is really annoying me getting stuck in this simple code...

Comment: What is the code in your form initialize event? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Adding to @braX comments, it would be useful if you can also highlight which line in your initialise event throws the error

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single procedure to call a userform.

```
Sub RunUserForm01()

    Dim Frm As UserForm01

    Set Frm = New UserForm01
    With Frm
        .TextBox1.Value = "Good morning"
        .Show
    End With

    Unload Frm
    Set Frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

`UserForm01` is the name of the form which appears in the Project Explorer list of UserForms. The code creates a new instance of that form here: `Set Frm = New UserForm01`. The initialize event will fire at that moment. Put a break point at that line and step through the following code with F8 to localize any missing object in the Initialize procedure.

After initialization you have access to all parts of the form. For example, you can set the value of controls as shown in my code for `TextBox1`. The same could have been done in the Initialize procedure a moment before but here you have better access to any worksheets and another set of variables you can declare in this procedure.

After `FrmShow` the form takes control of VBA. Control reverts to this point when the code encounters `Me.Hide` or the exit button is pressed. My code then unloads the form and deletes all memory of it.